# In Julia, how to skip certain numbers in a for loop

Tags: julia

In the julia for loop, I want to skip the numbers that can be divided by 500. For example, in the loop below, I want to skip i=500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, ..., 10000. How can I do that?

```
n=10000
result = zeros(n)
for i = 1:n
  result[i] = i
end
```

Comment: Maybe StatsBase.jl will work for you. You can get mode. Follow the link please:
https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/v0.20/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `continue`:

```
for i = 1:n
  iszero(i%500) && continue
  result[i] = i
end
```

Comment: Or even tighten that into a one-liner in the loop: `iszero(i%500) || result[i] = i`

Comment: Just a comment on how this is working. `i%500` is the remainder operator of the integer division, e.g. `10%4` is equal to 2, while `10%5` is equal to zero. Then the code exploit the so called [short-circuit evaluation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#Short-Circuit-Evaluation), that is if the first argument of an AND operator is true, Julia doesn't bother to check the second term, making suitable to use AND as an implicit if condition.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient option than `continue` would be to use `Iterators.filter` to create a lazy iterator which filters the values you don't require.

For the example given in the OP, this would be:

```
n=10000
result = zeros(n)
iter = Iterators.filter(i -> (i % 500) != 0, 1:n)
for i = iter
  result[i] = i
end
```

A benchmark comparing with @jling's answer:

```
julia> @btime for i = 1:n
         iszero(i%500) && continue
         result[i] = i
       end
  1.693 ms (28979 allocations: 609.06 KiB)

julia> @btime for i = iter
         result[i] = i
       end
  1.177 ms (28920 allocations: 607.81 KiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by @jing is perfectly correct, sometimes you have a list of values that you want to actually skip. In such cases `Not` may be an elegant solution:

```
julia> skipvals = [2,4,5];

julia> for i in (1:7)[Not(skipvals)]
       print("$i ")
       end
1 3 6 7
```

`Not` is a part of the `InvertedIndices` package, but also gets imported together via `DataFrames`, so in most data science codes it is just there for you to use :)